# How to get the border to change color in input focus

Tags: css

Please see this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".toggle-password").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
                var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
                if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
                    input.attr("type", "text");
                } else {
                    input.attr("type", "password");
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
.input-group .field-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ced4da;
}

.input-group-append, .input-group-text {
    border-left: 1px dashed #ced4da !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>AdminLTE 3 | Log in</title>

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- icheck bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/css/adminlte.min.css">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Admin</b>LTE</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

      <form action="../../index3.html" method="post">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span toggle="#Password" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
              <label for="remember">
                Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>

      <div class="social-auth-links text-center mb-3">
        <p>- OR -</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook mr-2"></i> Sign in using Facebook
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">
          <i class="fab fa-google-plus mr-2"></i> Sign in using Google+
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

      <p class="mb-1">
        <a href="forgot-password.html">I forgot my password</a>
      </p>
      <p class="mb-0">
        <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When you run it, you will see 2 squares to the right of the password field.

If you move the focus to that field, you will notice that all border get painted in blue but the left square area.

I know I could add a :focus modifier to the class in the CSS, but I did not find that modifier in the right square and it works, it get painted in blue when the focus is in the input control.

Maybe there is something I am missing.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly, but per my understanding, I can suggest to give an id to password field to access it on DOM and then you can apply :hover class.

Comment: It would be better if you clarify your question

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala this is not a functional problem but a visual one. Please click inside the password input field and see the border of the control. You will notice immediately the problem.

Comment: Yeah I saw that issue. But the css is forcing that. `.input-group .field-icon` is setting the different border forcefully.

Comment: That is precisely the question. How can I do that. Notice that the right most square does paint the border in blue (and it is also forcing the border to gray) and for it there is no a :focus modifier to repaint it in blue (notice also that the squares are outside the input control, so :focus modifier will not work), so I think there is a good way to accomplish it, that is, to paint the border in blue when the input focus is in the control.

Comment: The right most square does have border styles on focus, which left square doesn't. You can apply the similar styles to the left square as well and the problem sorted.
The right square selector:
.login-card-body .input-group .form-control:focus~.input-group-append .input-group-text, .register-card-body .input-group .form-control:focus~.input-group-append .input-group-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help. I have targeted the left square directly like `.login-card-body .input-group .form-control:focus~.input-group-append .field-icon`.

But it would be better if you give a unique id or class name to this span.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".toggle-password").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
                var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
                if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
                    input.attr("type", "text");
                } else {
                    input.attr("type", "password");
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
.input-group .field-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ced4da;
}

.input-group-append, .input-group-text {
    border-left: 1px dashed #ced4da !important;
}

.login-card-body .input-group .form-control:focus~.input-group-append .field-icon {
    border-top: 1px solid #80bdff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #80bdff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>AdminLTE 3 | Log in</title>

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- icheck bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/css/adminlte.min.css">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Admin</b>LTE</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

      <form action="../../index3.html" method="post">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span toggle="#Password" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
              <label for="remember">
                Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>

      <div class="social-auth-links text-center mb-3">
        <p>- OR -</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook mr-2"></i> Sign in using Facebook
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">
          <i class="fab fa-google-plus mr-2"></i> Sign in using Google+
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

      <p class="mb-1">
        <a href="forgot-password.html">I forgot my password</a>
      </p>
      <p class="mb-0">
        <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="https://www.desytec.com/adminlte/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It did it. I cound not find where the border color was being changed for the right square.